# (Stochastic) Time Series Reconstruction

Tags: stochastic-processes, machine-learning, regression, estimation, time-series

Assume a linear stochastic dynamical system
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}x&=-J_{1,1}x+J_{1,2}y+\sigma_{1}\,\mathrm{d}W_{1}\\\mathrm{d}y&=-J_{2,1}x-J_{2,2}y-\sigma_{1}\,\mathrm{d}W_{1}+\sigma_{2}\,\mathrm{d}W_{2}
\end{align}
$$
with the $J_{k,l}>0$ and two independent standard Wiener processes $W_1$ and $W_2$. We're looking here at the linearization of a non-linear system, that fluctuates around its steady state.

Assume we have long-time observations of a time series $x_{t}$ (with negligible measurement error for now) and know the structure of the above dynamical system. However, we have no direct access on $y_{t}$ and the parameter values are not (or only partially) known.

Here's my question:
Which method allows to **reconstruct the hidden time series** $y_{t}$ from the observed data $x_{t}$ and the known structure of the SDE system? If reconstructing the time series is too strong, then I would at least like to have an estimate of its statistical properties.

I assume this is a standard problem, but I'm a beginner in time series analysis and struggle with the zoo of available methods.

Comment: Honestly, I'd be surprised if anything about $y$ could be deduced from $x$. If (for simplicity) $k_4=0$ the SDE system is totally decoupled. Neither the mean of $y$ nor its variance has then anything to do with that of $x$. Allowing $k_4$ being non zero won't make it any simpler.

Comment: Hey Kurt! Thank you very much for your comment! I noticed that I have used the wrong equations. What do you think about the modified problem (see edit above)?

Comment: I think the same. Set $J_{1,2}=J_{2,1}=0$ to get the same decoupled system. Those $y$ and $x$ have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: But in my problem, $J_{1,2}$ and $J_{2,1}$ are definitely non-zero. Moreover, the Wiener process $W_1$ enters both equations. There must be some correlation here .... !?

Comment: That's true. However I bet that I could simulate in python two trajectories of $x$ and $y$ where you would have a very hard time to **reconstruct** (that bold setting is from you) $y$ from $x$. No matter what available method you use. Is there any restriction on $\sigma_2$ ? How large can it be compared to $\sigma_1$ ?

Comment: You are probably right that a direct reconstruction is too much wanted. After all, there is a second Wiener process $W_2$ that should make this practically impossible. Nevertheless: What are the most far-reaching statements I can make about $y$? Which of its statistical properties can be quantified? Which methods are helpful here?

Comment: You wrote that the parameters of $y$ are not or only partially known. Without knowing at least $\sigma_2$ I don't even see how to infer the correlation of $x$ and $y$ - assuming $\sigma_1$ is known or can be estimated from the time series.